# Scene graph with camera

Tags: opengl, rendering, matrix, view

I need help with a little problem in my project, in which I have a scene graph with the intented camera like this:

- MovementNode

  - Camera Node
  - Mesh Object

My problem is that I have the propagation of the world_space_matrix from the parent to the child done like this:

```
void BaseNode::update_matrix_if_needed() {
        if (_updated_position) {
            BaseNodeInstance* parent = instance.get_parent();

            global_space_matrix = glm::mat4(1.0f); // construct identity matrix

            //scale, rotate, move
                
                global_space_matrix = glm::scale(global_space_matrix, scl);
        
                rotation_matrix = glm::rotate(rot.x, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
                rotation_matrix *= glm::rotate(rot.y, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
                rotation_matrix *= glm::rotate(rot.z, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
                global_space_matrix =  rotation_matrix * global_space_matrix;

                global_space_matrix = glm::translate(local_space_matrix, pos);

            if (parent  != nullptr) {
                global_space_matrix = parent->get_data()->global_space_matrix * global_space_matrix;
            }
        }

        _updated_position = false;
    }
```

Then, in the Camera Node, I submit the view matrix like this:

```
void CameraNode::uniform_view_matrix(GLuint location) {
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location, 1, 0, glm::value_ptr(camera_matrix));
}
```

where `camera_matrix` is computed as:

```
void CameraNode::update(float delta) {
    //add_pos(glm::vec3(0, 0, -1) * delta);

    if (_updated_position) {
        BaseNode::update(delta);
        camera_matrix = global_space_matrix;
    }
}
```

However, when I move the camera in my application, the objects are moving in completely different directions than my camera (although they stick together how they should).

I think the problem is in how I interpret the view_matrix from the cameras local space. What can be my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was how I updated my Camera.

I used `global_space_matrix` as my view_matrix but then  I tried to use `glm::inverse(global_space_matrix)` and it is working as intended!

Still I don't completely understand why.